# One of my scripts is causing others in the same directory to have problems with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have multiple scripts in my python directory for pulling up various websites and logging me in and doing various other tasks. They work perfectly fine until I created another script to log into my email and now none of those scripts in that directory will work while that email script is in there. If I move the script to a different directory then all the previous ones work again but then the current directory with my email.py will have issues with selenium webdriver giving me the

"AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'"

Question is how do I fix this and why is it occurring with only that file?

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = 
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/users/roughcaster/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://sso.secureserver.net/login?app=email&realm=pass')
username = 
driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('trey@nationwideautoshipping.com')
password = driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('Ship2020*')
signin = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sign In').click()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: what is the name of that other script file?

Comment: the script file causing issues is email.py

Comment: is that already a file somewhere on my computer which causes conflicts using the same name?

Comment: What if you comment the line with `Chrome()`? What would the error say?

Comment: A bunch of other errors pop up for not driver not being defined. All the other files with Chrome() work its just this file in particular. Its pointing more and more at the file name I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is you called your directory `selenium` and if so you need to change the name.

If that is not the case double-check you have `selenium` installed.

Use `pip install selenium` to install.

Your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"/users/roughcaster/Downloads/chromedriver")
driver.get('https://sso.secureserver.net/login?app=email&realm=pass')

username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'username')))
username.send_keys('trey@nationwideautoshipping.com')
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'password')))
password.send_keys('Ship2020*')
signin = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'submitBtn')))
signin.click()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: What do you mean I called the directory selenium? Selenium is installed and works correctly. But not when the email.py file is in the same directory as my other scripts they will not work. If i move the email.py script to a different directory all the other scripts work fine.

Comment: The directories I have my scripts under is 'python' and then I move some of them to my home directory for easier access. None of them are called 'selenium'

Comment: @Roughcaster First, see python's [naming_conventions](https://visualgit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/naming_convention.html)

Comment: So I take it the file name is just too generic so its running into errors? I didnt find any other files that have that same name but still.. Now I am more curious than anything else exactly why that would run into errors being there is no other file with that name currently. Thank you!

Comment: @Roughcaster I don't know what else to say about your error... but try using the code snip in the edit of my answer...

Comment: I went with a different file name and the code you sent worked perfectly Moshe Slavin! Thank you

Comment: One more question, do I need to include a driver.quit() to make sure it doesnt take up more memory or with that quit the browser immediately?

Comment: @Roughcaster I'm glad to hear it worked! And yes you should add `driver.close()` and `driver.quit()` to make sure you don't fill the memory with driver instances!

Comment: Does the driver.close() .quit() execute immediately? I would be needing to stay on the sites and work for a bit before they exit. Also I upvoted but since my reputation isnt 15 yes it doesnt show a change. I just got on this site two days ago

Comment: @Roughcaster `driver.close() .quit()` will colse the browser immediately you can use [`try except finally`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) and in the `finally` part put the `driver.close() .quit()`

Comment: @Roughcaster If you find this answers your question you can accept it with the V under the voting area...

Comment: I clicked the checkmark under voting. Any other suggestions for closing the driver but only once I am finished with the site?One of them is for work so its a shortcut to login and get me to the correct pages

Comment: @Roughcaster I don't understand... If you want to work on the same driver (open page) I don't recommend to have the automation program close it... you'll need to have the program running all day! I hope this helps...